# How could I use a recursive method with an int parameter to return the number of zero digits in that int?

Tags: java, methods, recursion

the method is:

```
public static zeroCount(int num)
```

My instructor requires this method to have one int parameter and the recursive method must return the number of zeros in num.

So zeroCount(10200) = 3, and 
zeroCount(100300) = 4
etc...

I could easily do this but since I'm required to use a recursive method so I am completely lost.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: What if you keep dividing the number by 10 at each recursive step and return 1 if there is no remainder and 0 if there is?

Answer (score 0):

If you can approach the problem iteratively (that is, with  some kind of loop), then you can do it recursively.

The two things you'll need when writing the recursive method are:

- A **base case**; what you do when you have exhausted all digits of your number, and
- An **iterative case**; what you do when you still have more digits to go.

I also notice that you don't specify the return value of your method; ideally, it would be `int`.  Let that be a hint to you.

Answer (score 0):

You know that **x % 10** gives you the last digit of x, so you can use that to identify the zeros. Furthermore, after checking if a particular digit is zero you want to take that digit out, how? **divide by 10**.

```
public static int zeroCount(int num)
{
  int count = 0;

  if(num == 0) return 1;                  // stop case zeroCount(0)
  else if(Math.abs(num)  < 9)  return 0;  // stop case digit between 1..9 or -9..-1
  else
  {
   if (num % 10 == 0) // if the num last digit is zero
       count++; // count the zero, take num last digit out

   return count + zeroCount(num/10); // take num last digit out, and apply 
  } // the method recursively to the remaining digits 
}
```

I use math.Abs to allow negative numbers, you have to import java.lang.Math;

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
public int count0(int n) {
  if(n == 0) 
     return 0;
  if(n % 10 == 0) 
     return 1 + count0(n/10);

  return count0(n/10);
}
```